# MySQL WorkBench Hospital database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm learning MySQL with MySQL workbench and I have tried to code a hospital database but my problem is how can I know if I have enough beds-rooms for my patients? I have 5 tables:

```
t_patients (with idpatient, name, surname, n_card), 
t_doctor (with iddoctor, name, surname), 
t_ward (with idward, name), 
t_bed (with idbed, nbed, idward), 
t_ricovery (with idrecovery, idpatient, iddoctor, idbed, datericovery, datedischarge).
```

Can you help me? Sorry for my bad english and thank you

Comment: beds or bedrooms?

Comment: If you mean `beds`, then your current design implies you'd have to count active records in `t_ricovery` and compare it to the count of active `t_bed` records

Comment: we are happy to excuse poor english. English isn't my first language either. But we are not to so happy to excuse bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a SQL Solution , I think it is best to add a "bed_available" field to either your t_bed table or your t_patients which is **Boolean** , true/false or 1 / 0 .
this way you could use the function "**Count**" to count the number of free beds.

some thing like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_patients WHERE bed_available=true;
```

to read more about the COUNT function , try this link :
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

**There is another solution** , you could add a field (int),
write a trigger that adds or decreases 1 (a bed or bed-room) each time a field updates / deletes or is inserted !
like when someone gets a room the total number of the beds is decreased by one and when someone is released from hospital the number of the free beds gets a plus 1

hope it helps.

Comment: Is there the only solution? This is a school check, so
there should be a solution

Comment: Is that the only solution? This is a school check, so
there should be a solution

Comment: there is always more than one way to get the job done , I've updated my answer , but this is all i can think of given the information you have put on the website and my own knowledge.